# Not sure how to use ng lint in angular project

Tags: angular, lint

```
$ ng lint
Cannot find "lint" target for the specified project.
You can add a package that implements these capabilities.

For example:
  ESLint: ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
*****
```

I am expecting i am able to run ng lint and help me to find some error

Comment: I create one project which is example.
And I run the below command ->:ng lint

Comment: $ ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
- Determining package manager...
i Using package manager: npm
- Searching for compatible package version...
√ Found compatible package version: @angular-eslint/schematics@1.0.0.
- Loading package information from registry...
√ Package information loaded.
No terminal detected. '--skip-confirmation' can be used to bypass installation confirmation. Ensure package name is correct prior to '--skip-confirmation' option usage.
Command aborted.

Answer (score 0):

ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@14 --skip-confirmation
To use the above command to install package as my angular version is 14.